# how to read binary file in vb script when ActiveX is used

Tags: vbscript

I am getting error like cant use `ado.stream` when ActiveX is used.

I tried searching but I could not found any thing other than `ado.stream` to read binary files in vbscript

```
dim FileName
dim resstring
Function ReadBinaryFile(FileName)
  Const adTypeBinary = 1


  Dim BinaryStream
  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")


  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary


  BinaryStream.Open


  BinaryStream.LoadFromFile FileName


  ReadBinaryFile = BinaryStream.Read
End Function
```

and called like below
resstring =ReadBinaryFile("C:\Documents and Settings\mahesh\Desktop\img.iso")

Comment: The function works fine here. What's the exact error? It may just be some ActiveX components that are not registered correctly on a machine (I've had some such errors here and there). You could try it on a different computer for testing.

Comment: Webpage error details

Message: ActiveX component can't create object: 'ADODB.Stream'
Line: 62